# error: blackarch: signature from "Levon 'noptrix' Kayan (BlackArch Developer)

Tags: linux-kernel, archlinux-arm

error: blackarch: signature from "Levon 'noptrix' Kayan (BlackArch Developer) noptrix@nullsecurity.net" is unknown trust error: database 'blackarch' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))

I trynig so much solution but its not working for me. Any one know this broblem solution please
please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://github.com/BlackArch/blackarch/issues/4018):

```
curl -O https://blackarch.org/strap.sh
chmod +x strap.sh 
./strap.sh 
sudo ./strap.sh 
sudo pacman -Syu
```